# How do you handle NULL values in DataBound controls?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, label, databound

I am trying to limit the characters displayed in ASP.NET Label controls that have their Text values databound to a SQL Database. If the field in the database is not NULL, I do not have any trouble. If they are NULL, I get the exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

My code is as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# IIf(Not IsDBNull(Item.LabelDescription), IIf(Item.LabelDescription.ToString.Length > 30, Left(Item.LabelDescription, 30) & "...", Item.LabelDescription), Item.LabelDescription)%>' />
```

I have also tried the following, without any luck:

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelDescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# IIf(Not IsNothing(Item.LabelDescription), IIf(Item.LabelDescription.ToString.Length > 30, Left(Item.LabelDescription, 30) & "...", Item.LabelDescription), Item.LabelDescription)%>' />
```

I am using ASP.NET with VB.NET. I have tried using the CSS "text-overflow: ellipsis" method as well, but I had some table formatting issues that I have not resolved.

Is there a way to handle these NULL values and prevent run-time exceptions?

Thanks!

Comment: use the new(ish) [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) instead of `IIF` to short circuit the evaluations.  `IIF` will evaluate all elements/clause so that `Item.LabelDescription.ToString.Length` will cause the exception even though you tried to test for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you are having is that the old `IIF` is a function which evaluates all the parts before it decides what to return.

```
IIF(Not IsDBNull(Item.LabelDescription), TruePart, FalsePart)
```

It does not matter if the expression is true or not, the `TruePart` and 
`FalsePart` statements will always be executed.  Since they include references to something which may be DBNull/Nothing/null, you get an error.

Something else though is that Nothing is not the same as DBNull, and if `Item` is an Object which can be Nothing/null, then testing the description of Nothing/null will be problematic.

The [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) has been available since abut 2008.  The structure is the same but it only evaluates the test condition and the True **or** False expression which applies:

```
If( Condition, TruePart, FalsePart )
```

The "short circuiting" prevents the expression/Part which does not apply from being evaluated.  As long as the rest of the code is valid, you should be able to just clip one of the `I`s from the `IIF` functions.

Since you want to the object Nothing I would use the `Nothing` keyword rather than the VB `IsNothing` function:

```
If(Item IsNot Nothing), 
        If(Item.LabelDescription.ToString.Length > 30, x, y), y)
```

The If operator is not the same as the If/Then/Else statement block.